# ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: python, random-forest, train-test-split

I have the following code for splitting data :

```
# Convert dataframe column of images into numpy array
X = np.asarray(skin_df_balanced['image'].tolist())
X = X/255.  # Scale values to 0-1. You can also used standardscaler or other scaling methods.
Y=skin_df_balanced['label']  # Assign label values to Y
Y_cat = to_categorical(Y, num_classes=7) #Convert to categorical as this is a multiclass classification problem

# Split to training and testing
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y_cat, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
```

with random forest I found the error, pleasse help me with this code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rfc  = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=28)
rfc.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

It raises the following error:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Comment: I'm guessing that each cell in `skin_df_balanced['image']` is a two-dimensional array? If so, you need to reshape them into vectors, so that they can be fed into the classifier.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `skin_df_balanced['image'].tolist()` gives you a list of images, where each image is a 3-d array with shape `(height, width, num_channels)` (`num_channels` is likely 3 if those are RGB images for example). If this correct, then you need to 'flatten' each of the images into a vector first. It is a simple change to that first line of code:

```
X = np.asarray([img.ravel() for img in skin_df_balanced['image'].tolist()])
```

More fundamentally however, you are using your image pixels as you feature to an RF classifier which is not something I would recommend because of the very high number of features. (This is related to the so-called "curse of dimensionality.") I hope that you have a lot of images to train...